# Coq: rewrite preserving input hypothesis

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I would like to rewrite a hypothesis while keeping the old version, and saving the result of the rewrite under a new name. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the shorter I can think of:

```
Lemma test T (P : T -> Prop) (x y : T) (heq : x = y) (hp : P x) : False.
Proof.
pose proof hp; rewrite heq in hp.
```

However YMMV, usually when using ssreflect I get to manage my hypotheses in such a way that I don't have to resort to these tricks often.